# How to drop particular record with some junk characters(like $,"NA",etc) from CSV file using PYSPARK

Tags: pyspark

I have a CSV file, from which I want to remove records which have particular characters like "$", "NA", "##".
I am not able to figure out any function to drop the records for this scenario.
How can I achieve this?

Hello All,
 I tried below code and it is working fine.But this code for paricular pattern 
 and i want to remove multiple occurances of garbage 
 values(#,##,###,$,$$,$$$)like this.

eg] filter_list = ['##', '$']

```
df = df.filter(df.color.isin(*filter_list) == False)

df.show()

In this example I used single column is "color", but instead of a single column 

I want to work with multiple columns (passing array).
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the filter function
(http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter)

Here's some example code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

#create some test data
df = spark.createDataFrame([(17, "2017-03-10T15:27:18+00:00", "orange"),
                (13, "2017-03-15T12:27:18+00:00", "$"),
                (25, "2017-03-18T11:27:18+00:00", "##")],
                ["dollars", "timestampGMT", "color"])

df.show()
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
+-------+--------------------+------+
|dollars|        timestampGMT| color|
+-------+--------------------+------+
|     17|2017-03-10T15:27:...|orange|
|     13|2017-03-15T12:27:...|     $|
|     25|2017-03-18T11:27:...|    ##|
+-------+--------------------+------+
```

You can create a filter list and then filter out the records that match (in this case from the color column):

```
filter_list = ['##', '$']

df = df.filter(df.color.isin(*filter_list) == False)

df.show()
```

Here's what the data looks like now:

```
+-------+--------------------+------+
|dollars|        timestampGMT| color|
+-------+--------------------+------+
|     17|2017-03-10T15:27:...|orange|
+-------+--------------------+------+
```

Comment: No problem.  If this solution works for you, feel free to upvote it, and/or mark it as accepted.